# Get the next time that respect a time format and not a pervious one

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, date-manipulation

I am trying to get the time to the next "6:00:00", I am using moment:

```
let shiftEnd =  moment("06:00:00", "HH:mm:ss")
console.log(shiftEnd.inspect())
```

It gets me the previous 6:00:00, the one with the same day as `now()`.

```
moment("2017-07-31T06:00:00.000")
```

`now()` is:

```
moment("2017-07-31T12:20:57.076")
```

What's the best way to get the next 6am that's not passed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a moment object for the current day because, as moment [Default](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/) section states:

> You can create a moment object specifying only some of the units, and the rest will be defaulted to the current day, month or year, or 0 for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

You can simply test if your moment object is in the past (using [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)) and [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) 1 day if needed.

Here a live example:

```js
let shiftEnd =  moment("06:00:00", "HH:mm:ss")

if( shiftEnd.isBefore(moment()) ){
  shiftEnd.add(1, 'd')
}

console.log(shiftEnd.inspect())
console.log(shiftEnd.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `day` method to get the current day of week number, and then add one to the day of the week to get tomorrow day of week:

```
    var now = moment(), day;

    // check if before 6 am get the current day, otherwise get tomorrow
    if(now.hour() < 6)
       day = now.day();
    else
       day = now.day() + 1;
```

Then to get tomorrow 6 am use `isoWeekDay` to get the moment object from the number of the day of week and set hour to 6 and minutes and seconds to 0:

```
var tomorrow = moment().isoWeekday(day).hour(6).minute(0).second(0)
```

tomorrow will be `2017-08-01T06:00:00+02:00`

Comment: this solution fails if it's 5am for example

Comment: yes, but you can simply check the current hour with hour method ( moment().hour()), and if it's less then 6 get the current day otherwise get the next. Updated my answer