# How do I calculate hours from PM to AM using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I've been working on calculating the total hours, minutes and seconds between two times using the moment.js library.  The problem I have is that the calculations don't recognise that it's a day and return more hours than what is there.  I'll give you an example:

I want to know how many hours are between `21:00` and `06:00`, the answer is `9`, however, the calculation brings back `-15`, this is also technically correct.  I need to tell moment that it should use a day to calculate this value.  I can get it to work if I use a DateTime picker but I don't want to use that as the user is only required to provide a time.

> My application uses KendoUI for MVC and moment.js, moment.duration.format.js and moment.range.js

Here is my code which will return `-15`

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker().Name("start").Value("21:00"))
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker().Name("end").Value("06:00"))

<button class="btn btn-default btn-success" onclick="calc()">Plot</button>
```

Here is the javascript that works with this.

```
 function calc() {

   window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

    console.clear();

    var dformat = "HH:mm:ss";                     
    var start = $("#start").data("kendoTimePicker").value();
    var end = $("#end").data("kendoTimePicker").value();           

    var startTime = moment(kendo.toString(start));
    var endTime = moment(kendo.toString(end));
    var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
    var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
    console.log(hours);    
}
```

If we change this to use `DateTimePicker` instead, it understands there is a day and calculates `9` hours.  So how do I get around this?  How can I achive this without using a datetime picker?  Can I leaverage `moment.js` `startof` day or something?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45414587/4131048), you are getting a moment object for the current day, use `isBefore` and `add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VincenzoC I have managed to fix this problem.  Here is the code which checks if the end time is before the start time and if it is, add a single day.  This means the resulting time is accurate.

```
var startTime = moment(start);
var endTime = moment(end);

if (endTime.isBefore(startTime))
{
    endTime.add(1, 'd');

}

//
//After the above condition has been passed, calculate the difference
var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));

//
//Any format you want
console.log(duration.format("HH"))
```